# import statement in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have 3 different TS file and loading  2 TS file dynamically as below in 1 main TS file

```
if(x==='xyz'){
  import('../../common1').then((common)=>{
    common.loadContent()
  })
} else if(x==='abc'){
  import('../../common2').then((common)=>{
    common.loadContent()
  })
}
```

Now in both TS file I am importing jquery and also import jquery parent TS file

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@microsoft"],
    "types": ["es6-promise", "webpack-env"],
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "es2015.collection"]
  }
}
```

So my question is do jquery **file** will load 3 times or only once.

Comment: Is your code running in Node.JS or in the browser?

Comment: @blaumeise20 it is running in browser

Comment: Using webpack or with `type="module"` ?

Comment: @blaumeise20 webpack

Comment: Can you please add your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @blaumeise20 I updated my original question with tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is a bit unpredictable in this case, [I'm struggling with it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110760/dont-bundle-lazy-loaded-chunk-specified-in-webpack-config), but I don't think it will be loaded multiple times. After the first time it is cached and will be taken from the module cache. The only important thing is that you set the `module` type in the tsconfig.json to "esnext", what you have done.