# Don't bundle lazy loaded chunk specified in webpack config

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading

I have a file structure like this (simplified):

```
src/
  index.ts
  lazy.ts
  something.ts
webpack.config.js
```

In `index.ts` I import `lazy.ts` using async import. In both modules I import `something.ts`. Because `something.ts` is bundled with `index.ts` in the main chunk I have to tell webpack that it should use the same module cache for `lazy.ts`. Or did I understand something wrong? So I specified a chunk in webpack.config.js that depends on the main chunk and has the `lazy.ts` entry. Now I get three chunks instead of two because webpack bundles `lazy.ts` twice. How can I solve that?